# Free variables system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

If you have a system fo linear equations, the solution is where the equations intersect

Using row reduction you get a system of linear equations which still satisfies the intersection

Why are free variables used?

The values in which the free variable can be are limited in a range as for if the solution is a line and not a plane

So what is the point in writing the solutions as a set of vector additions using free variables?

If z in this case is a free variable, writing the solution in a vector equation

Where , denotes a new row

Solving for the pivot variables x and y and writing into decomposed vector form

[x,y] = [4,0] - [0,3] + z[1,2]

Z is said to be any real number zeR
But looking at the graph, when z = 4, y=11/8 is not on the line of intersection
So why do they say that z is a free variable when it isnt?

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wujVl.png)

Gren = y axis
Red = x axis
[Graphed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaiAJ.png)

Comment: You’re right, it isn’t on the line, but neither is $11/8$ what you get for the $y$-coordinate when you plug $z=4$ into the immediately preceding formula, so there’s no reason to expect that it would be.

Comment: "Why are free variables used?" Your observation that "the solution is where the equations intersect" is the key to this. If you think about two planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$, they usually intersect in a line (unless the planes are parallel or coinciding). So intuitively, we will have one free variable, because a line is determined by one variable.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of free variables is that every free variable can have any value whatsoever, so they are really FREE. Once the values of the free variables have been chosen, there is no more freedom at all. The values of the remaining variables are completely determined by those of the free variables. So the free variables are totally free and the non-free variables are totally imprisoned.